# Show that if $f$ is Hölder continuous with exponent 0 < $α$ ≤ 1. then $f$ is continuous

Tags: real-analysis

$f$:$T$→$R$ is said to be Hölder continuous if ∃$α$>0 such that |$f$($x$)−$f$($x$')|≤ $L$|$x$−$x$'|$^α$.

In order to prove that if $f$ is Hölder continuous then $f$  is continuous, 
we must show that $f$ is uniformly continuous.
So if we  show that |$f$($x$)−$f$($x$')| ≤ $L$|$x$−$x$'|$^α$ ≤ $L$|$x$−$x$'|, since $α$≤1. This implies that $f$ is Lipschitz ⇒ $f$ is uniformly continuous ⇒ $f$ is continuous.

Is my way of proving is correct?

Comment: *we must show that* $f$ *is uniformly continuous* --- This is far, far from clear to me, and in fact I seriously doubt it's true or even provable in some sense. On the other hand, you **can** show that $f$ is continuous by showing the stronger result that $f$ is uniformly continuous. The distinction is like saying "to show that $x > 5$ we **must** show that $x > 500$" (no, this is not true, because there are other ways --- for example, if you could show $x > 15$ --- and besides, we might not even have $x > 500)$ vs. "one way to show $x > 5$ is to show the stronger result $x > 500$".

Answer (score 1):

$\alpha -$Holder for $\alpha \in (0,1)$ doesn't implies that $f$ is Lipschitz. For example, $x\mapsto \sqrt x$ is $\frac{1}{2}-$Holder on $[0,1]$, but not Lipschitz and $[0,1]$. Let $L>0$ be s.t. $$|f(x)-f(y)|\leq L|x-y|^\alpha ,$$
for all $x,y\in T$. Let $\varepsilon >0$ and take $\delta =\frac{\varepsilon ^{1/\alpha }}{L}$. Then $$|x-y|<\delta \implies |f(x)-f(y)|<\varepsilon ,$$
and thus $f$ is uniformly continuous and thus continuous.